# ngForm not work in web application, but does in jsFiddle

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use the `$invalid` properties of ngForm to disable a submit button in my app. For some reason, the FormController instance that I should have access to after the `<form>` is created is not available. However, I moved the code over to jsFiddle and for some reason it works now.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj2tu/7/)

In my real application, there are no errors in the console and I am including angular.min.js correctly because everything else works fine. I am lost on what to try next since the code is basically the same in both.

Comment: Is it that the button is always disabled or always not? Is the fiddle your entire project in its entirety or just a piece of a bigger project? You need to provide more info!

Comment: Sorry, but I tried losing most of the other code in my project and it still didn't work. The button is always enabled because the <form> is never creating a FormController I believe

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what is in your controller this is just a guess, but when I have problems with things not working for obscure reasons I generally am able to solve the problem by creating an object in scope and hanging everything off of it (much like you have already done.)

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
        email:'',
        employees:'',
        migDate:''
    };

}
```

The trick here is that you need to name your form similarly:

```
<form name="form.newMigForm" novalidate ng-controller="myControllerName">
```

and then when you check $invalid in your button, you use the same convention:

```
<input id="qaStartForm" ng-disabled="form.newMigForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitNewMigration()" type="button" class="btnOrangeLarge" value="Start" />
```

This problem generally arises when you use the UI Modal and they tell you to access it like this in the docs. I have used it successfully in other areas and solved the mystery that was plaguing me.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried that and still no luck. I can't show all of the HTML because it is a massive file once our CMS gets involved and renders the full web page. This is what makes debugging it difficult

Comment: You might try specifying the controller on the form. Example edited.